# How can I code this `if statement` within one line?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-3

Is there any possible way to code this in one line? sometthing like <%= "A" if .......>

```
<% if @box == 'inbox' && m.is_read?(current_user) %>
A
<% else %>
B
<% end %>
```

Comment: Minor design thing: If your `box` only takes a small set of values it's better not to hardcode it as a string, but use symbols instead, e.g. `if @box == :inbox`.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You need a ternary operator – also known as the "conditional" operator in Ruby, which returns "A" if the expression before `?` is true, and "B" if the expression is false.

```
<%= (@box == 'inbox' && m.is_read?(current_user)) ? "A" : "B" %>
```

Comment: You can simply nest these statements, e.g., `expr ? (expr ? ret_true : ret_false) : ret_false`, but I would really recommend against that. There's huge tradeoff in readability here.

Comment: @HUSTEN Can you explain why you want everything on one line?

Comment: because it looks more sophisticated

Comment: @HUSTEN I see… you're welcome. Note though: A Ruby programmer—and generally, anyone who needs to maintenance your code later on—would probably trade readability against *anything* looking "sophisticated" just for the sake of it.

Answer (score 2):

A ternary operator will do the trick(see other answers for how to use it), but I advice you strongly against using it here. Using a ternary opperator you will reduce the code but your readability will suffer greatly for that.

Comment: +1 I hate seeing the ternary operator for chained conditions, it makes things less readable. Who cares if it's on one line?

Comment: Good point, actually. At least in this case, it doesn't make things prettier.

Comment: I would also recommend changing the "m" variable to "message" (assuming that's what it is). It will be more readable that way.

Answer (score 0):

A ternary gains you nothing but headache in the view layer; the logic should be in a helper, e.g.,

```ruby
def inbox_msg_read?(box, msg)
  box == 'inbox' && msg.is_read?(current_user)
end

<%= inbox_msg_read?(@box, msg) ? 'A' : 'B' %>
```

Depending on what's actually happening here I might move the 'A'/'B' part into a helper as well.

I'd move the "inbox" logic to either a helper method or into the mailbox object:

```
box.inbox? && msg.is_read?(current_user)
```

This isolates inbox logic to a single location (e.g., not scattered across an arbitrary number of view files) and creates a single focal point if you need additional logic for other boxes (e.g., "trash" or something).

It also provides a hint that something metaprogrammatic might be useful for identifying boxes if there's any number of well-known boxes (e.g., trash, sent, today, etc.) It all depends on what's happening.

Scattering logic like this across the view layer makes refactorings less obvious, and forces multiple points of change when the logic/output needs change.